# Grails - Acegi: Customize Authentication Method

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I want to change the authentication process that is used by the Acegi - Plugin. It should be a completely customized process. Custom login form + custom auth method.

Obviously there is only little documentation regarding this topic.

In the book *The Definitive Guide to Grails* it is described for an older version of grails. There the `spring/resources.xml` is used.

In the new version is a `spring/resources.groovy` file, where a DSL is used. I don't know how to configure a new `AuthenticationManager`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In respect to the form, you should have a *auth.gsp* under */grails-wapp/views/login*. In respect to authentication, you probably only need to injet a different AuthenticateService in *LoginController*, which is under */grails-app/controllers/*.